# Email not sending from admin panel

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to have the Django admin send emails to the users of the site.  However, I cannot get the email to send to a user's email inbox. There doesn't seem to be any compile issues but I don't get anything in my inbox.  What exactly is going wrong? I made sure to set up email in Django correctly, too.  Here is my code:

views.py

```
def sendUserEmails(request):
    form = SendEmailForm(request.POST)
    print("going here")
    if form.is_valid():
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        users = form.cleaned_data['users']

        for user in users:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, user.email, fail_silently = True)

        user_message = '{0} users emailed successfully!'.format(form.cleaned_data['users'].count())
        messages.success(self.request, user_message)

    return render(request, 'admin/send_email.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class SendEmailForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Subject'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    users = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(label = "To", queryset = Account.objects.all(), widget = forms.SelectMultiple())
```

email function in admin.py

```
def send_email(self, request, queryset):
    form = SendEmailForm(initial = {'users' : queryset})
    return render(request, 'admin/send_email.html', {'form': form})
```

urls.py

```
path('admin/solutions/account/', views.sendUserEmails, name='email'),
```

I tried to debug with no success.  Please help.

Comment: I'd start with changing `fail_silently` to `False` so that failures in `send_email` are propagated. That will likely tell you what the issue is. If it doesn't, then you need to check the logs for whatever email backend/service you have configured.

Comment: If my email backend is a random gmail account, then where would I find the error logs?

Comment: Your email backend isn't the gmail account, it is the email backend you have configured Django to use - most likely the SMTP backend. If that is the case then changing `fail_silently` will report the error.

Comment: Ah, that's right.  Forgive me, but I'm still very new to Django.  So I turned fail_silently to false.  Where would the error logs be? In the console?

Comment: If you're running in debug mode on the local development server, then the error and stack trace will be displayed on the page itself when you try to submit the form.

Comment: I see. I don't see anything out of the ordinary though. No errors. No stacktrace whatsoever.

Comment: You did not share email configuration. If email sending code works fine then probably sites email inside spam or search in promotions. If you are using gmail did you do  Allow less secure apps: ON
https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?pli=1

Comment: It's just this: EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend' .  I didn't see email inside my spam folder or anything, and when I tested the project in other places where email is sent it works perfectly.